# Issue while installing FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I simply get this error after performing all tasks described in the official documentation:[Sonata userBundle Install guide](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-0/doc/reference/installation.html)

**`Bundle "SonataUserBundle" extends bundle "FOSUserBundle", which is not registered.`**

While I succesfully installed SonataUserBundle (which include FOS) & updated the config & appkernel.

PS: already have AdminBundle installed
UPDATE1: Now I added `new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle()` & I got this error InvalidArgumentException: Bundle "ApplicationSonataUserBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled.

Comment: Look at your `AppKernel.php` - is `FOSUserBundle` registered there?

Comment: I just had `new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle')`,
Now I added `new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle()` & I got this error `InvalidArgumentException: Bundle "ApplicationSonataUserBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled.`

Comment: I'd say that is the next bundle you need to enable in `AppKernel`

Comment: What version of symfony are you running the docs you provided for the user bundle are old. Try using the latest ones http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html

Comment: I jus starte learning symfony so I have the last version downloaded just 2 weeks ago, same for the userbundle.
@dmnptr already enabled in app kernel I have `   new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
   new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
   new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to extend sonata user, see here section 2.5 http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html

You have to keep the line `new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle')` and remove new `FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle`